# MVC Bind Dropdownlist to Enum while Grouping

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core-mvc

In .NET core MVC using `asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof (Atlantis.Common.Enums.MyEnumtype))"` would create a flat list. However, I had to create a grouping enum using the `[Flags]` attribute. My enum looks like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum ReferralSource
{
    ReligiousOrganizations = 1,
    CommunityOutreach = 2,
    CommunityMailing = 3,
    NewsPaper = 4,
    FosterParent = 5,
    TFCStaff = 6,
    Internal = ReligiousOrganizations | CommunityOutreach | CommunityMailing | NewsPaper,
    External = FosterParent | TFCStaff | TFCStaff
}
```

I need to convert this enum to a series of `optgroup` and `option` in my `select`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to build it out yourself using reflection. There is nothing built into ASP.NET to do what you’re asking for automatically.

Also, I think you mean to Make those Flags values powers of 2...  1, 2, 4, 8, etc.

Comment: You're right ab out the power of 2. I didn't realize `flags` indicates an enum can be treated as a bit field.